# MODIS L2 (OC,SST...) netCDF4 via array to Geotiff - distortion problem with Python

Tags: python, gdal, modis, netcdf

I am struggling with the conversion of a subdataset of MODIS L2 .nc files.
I have i.e. a MODIS L2 OC file and want to extract one subdataset like clorophyl (chlor_a) and convert it to a Geotiff file.
Below my script Im using now, but which results in a distortion of the geotiff.
What am I doing wrong? Here a link to such a file (A2016216035000.L2_LAC_OC.nc)
[Link to an example MODIS file](http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/browse.pl?sub=level1or2&per=CU&day=17016&prm=CHL&set=10&mon=16983&sen=am&rad=0&frc=0&n=74.8828125&w=130.4296875&id=1470215143.3631&cn=75.60&cs=73.94&cw=127.49&ce=135.00&dnm=D&file=A2016216035000.L2_LAC_OC_CHLOR_A_BRS&ndx=1&wid=170&hgt=254)

```
import numpy as np,shutil
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdal_array
from osgeo import osr

filepath = r"Z:\rasterdata\modis\test\OC_Test\raw\_4_A2016216035000.L2_LAC_OC.nc"
dataset = Dataset(filepath,"r")
gd=dataset.groups['geophysical_data']
nav=dataset.groups['navigation_data']
lons = nav.variables["longitude"][:]
lats = nav.variables["latitude"][:]

flags= gd.variables["l2_flags"][:]

lat=np.array(lats)
lon=np.array(lons)

for row in flags:
    Data=[]
    EineReihe=row
    for Element in EineReihe:
        BinNum=bin(Element)
        if BinNum[-2]=="1":
            Data.append("1")
        else:
            Data.append(np.nan)
    if RowCount==0:
        A=np.array(Data)
    else:
        A = np.vstack((A, np.array(Data)))
    RowCount+=1

xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = [lon.min(),lat.min(),lon.max(),lat.max()]
nrows,ncols = np.shape(A)
xres = (xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres = (ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres)   

output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(r"Z:\rasterdata\modis\test\OC_Test\_4_y.tif",ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)  # Open the file
output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)  # Specify its coordinates
srs = osr.SpatialReference()                 # Establish its coordinate encoding
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)                     # This one specifies WGS84 lat long.

output_raster.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )   # Exports the coordinate system 
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(A)   # Writes my array to the raster

output_raster = None
```

In the for loop, this code example should extract the Land mask to (land =1) Water =nan - just to have a better reference to check the result.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `gdal_translate`? From the command line, run:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff Z:\rasterdata\modis\test\OC_Test\raw\_4_A2016216035000.L2_LAC_OC.nc:chlor_a outfile.tif`

More info: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Comment: Because this is giving a wrong output as well.
Its distortied in longitude. Just try it and you will see it.
You should use 
gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF5:Z:\rasterdata\modis\test\OC_Test\raw\_4_A2016216035000.L2_LAC_OC.nc://geophysical_data/chlor_a outfile.tif